# Keep original image height and size in html

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to print a simple image of size 103 X 99 in between lines. However, returning the image like

```
<div class="myClass">
  ...Text very long text
  <img src="../myimageLink">
</div>
```

The above makes the image accodate the whole myClass width and the remaining size. To fix it i had to set the img `height` and width styling property. I am wondering, is there any way i can regain the image ratio and original size without explicitly using the `height` and the `width` ?

Comment: Only set width or height?

Comment: Please add a code snippet or fiddle so we can see what happens.

Comment: There is no reason why the image shouldn't be displayed in its original size. Please post more info about your CSS and markup.

Comment: This is very unclear. Please create a JS Fiddle or post your CSS.

Comment: NB: You should explicitly set height and width in any case, so that the browser doesn't need to redraw the page after loading the image.

Answer (score 3):

As i understand from your question you want to get the original size of the image
so you can use in CSS the `auto` proprietary like `height:auto;`